# Web resources waiting a long time in chrome

Tags: angularjs, image, google-chrome

So I am pulling several images (100+) from cloudinary and showing them on a webpage. Some images download instantly but others take a long time. They are all the exact same image size.

I think that this has to do with the simultaneous requests that chrome can process at once but I'm not sure.

**How do I decrease this wait time?**

Here is the devtools network tab:
[image: http://puu.sh/hEHuV/1352cacafd.png]

The time of just the images. Note: many images are the same.

[image: http://puu.sh/hEHBy/1d0a2dfb65.png]

They are the same only for testing.

If you need any more details, let me know.

Here is a sample of one of the images: http://res.cloudinary.com/hcdhs6akl/image/upload/w_375,c_fit/v1430929395/Moodboard%20Images/ehkabs82dmpab7c4ri72.jpg

Two of the exact same images with different times:
http://puu.sh/hDEAS/17efd19b80.png[image]

Comment: Are they all coming from the same server url?  I believe HTTP 1.1 only allows three simultaneous downloads from any one url.  Also how large (in pixel size) are the images?  Judging by the filesize I am guessing 1024x1024 ish...  Try processing them down using ImageMagick or Photoshop/Fireworks

Comment: They are all coming form cloudinary.com/**/* does that qualify as the same server url?

Comment: Dont forget it could also be the client bandwidth

Comment: Yeah that counts as same URL; also as @David Grinberg pointed out there may be other factors.

Comment: Your images seemed to be compressed very well; I am not sure you can get them much smaller without lowering the JPG compression quality.  I was able to half the size by dropping the quality to 60% with ImageMagick.  `convert C:\test.jpg -quality 60% C:\test_resized.jpg`

Comment: I can't really make the quality drop in this case due to client demands :(

Comment: How do you usually get around this? Download them all in one request to a local temp folder and render from there?

Comment: Can you whitelist a connection for chrome to allow more?